# Synchronization and static Synchronization

Tags: java, synchronized

I am trying to understand the main difference between synchronized and static-synchronized methods.

For instance considering an `Employee` class that has a couple of instances `e1`, `e2`.

```
synchronized method1() {
    //--- blah blah---
}
```

When `e1` is executing `method1()` by acquiring object level lock, `e2` would be waiting for the lock to be released which was hwld by `e1`.

In case of static-synchronized also when `e1` holding the lock at class level, `e2` can't enter into that block.

```
static synchronized method1() {
    //--- blah blah---
}
```

How are those two cases different? I dont see any difference bwtween static and non-static synchronized method access.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the synchronization is operated at the instance level, so if you call `e1.method1()` and `e2.method1()` concurrently, they are allowed to run in parallel.

In your second example, the synchronization is operated at the class level, so if you call `e1.method1()` and `e2.method1()` concurrently, they will NOT run in parallel.

Comment: in first example, are you sure that both e1 and e2 can run parallel? Is it not contradictory to synchronized concept?

Comment: @BalajiG Am I sure: yes / Is it contradictory: no. The first example is equivalent to `void method1() { synchronized(this) { ...} }`. So if you run `e1.method1(); e2.method1();` they will lock on `e1` and `e2` respectively. Since these are different locks they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: The second example is equivalent to `static void method1() { synchronized(MyClass.class) {...} }` - in that case, the lock is the same for all instances (`Myclass.class`) and all calls are mutually exclusive.